# Setting pytest-benchmark configurations in pytest.ini

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, pytest, ini, pytest-benchmark

I am trying to setup the pytest.ini configuration file such that any benchmark test runs with the "--benchmark-autosave" option as on and other tests do not.

I have tried adding the option in the ini file as follows...

```
[pytest]
addopts = --benchmark-autosave
```

However it runs this option with every tests resulting in PytestBenchmarkWarning warnings. I am wondering if there is a way just to run this option on pytests that have benchmark used.

I have looked into...

```
[pytest]
addopts = --benchmark-autosave
filterwarnings = 
     ignore::PytestBenchmarkWarning
```

However, I get this error:

```
INTERNALERROR> warnings. OptionError: unknown warning category: 'PytestBenchmarkWarning'
```

If I have the tests as follows
test_a.py

```
import a
import pytest

def test_a(benchmark):
     benchmark(a.func)
```

test_b.py

```
import b
import pytest

def test_b():
     b.func()
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --benchmark-autosave
filterwarnings = 
     ignore::PytestBenchmarkWarning
```

with file structure:

```
my_project/src/a.py
my_project/src/b.py
my_project/test/test_a.py
my_project/test/test_b.py
my_project/pytest.ini
```

Under a terminal:

```
cd my_project
pytest test/
```

Comment: Why don't you show the warning? I don't get any warnings with latest package versions, try bumping package and deps to latest version with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pytest-benchmark`

Comment: As for the warnings filter, you need to provide full import name of the warning class (so `pytest` can actually import the class). `ignore::pytest_benchmark.logger.PytestBenchmarkWarning` should work.

Comment: Ahh yeah your right, I should have said in my post, under terminal if you ran `pytest test/b.py` it would give a warning when I wouldn't want it to.

Comment: Then it's code in `b.py` that is raising the warning, not your test code.